# How can I change the format of my date using Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

Hello I am programming using AngularJS, here is my code :

```
ng-options="item as item.creattion for item in list"
```

But the format of my date is : "2019-07-01T12:44:58.660Z"

Or I just want to have this :

```
"2019-07-01 12:44"
```

How can I do this ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular filters to format the date.For example
{{date | date:'yyyy:MM:dd hh:ss'}}

For Reference please check this example made by me:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G5LNI1AD7D1L

Or second way incase it doesn't solve your problem.You can user momentJS with angular for formatting dates.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

I hope this will solve your problem..Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use angularjs date filter `{{item.date | date:'dd:MM:yyyy hh:ss'}}`